# I want to use the bio-metric fingerprint scanner in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I want to use the bio-metric fingerprint scanner in Angular 7. Can anyone suggest which library I should be using in Angular 7 ?

Comment: nativescript-fingerprint-auth

Comment: Check out [Web Authentication API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API)